# What can I do to receive LG SimpLink signals on my PC?

Tags: windows-7, connection, hdmi, remote-control

Is it possible to receive LG SimpLink signals on PC?

I have an LG TV connected to PC with HDMI, and I want to manage JetAudio with the remote controller of the TV.

I think the TV behaves like a "SimpLink server" and sends the button press events to the connected devices, so I can handle the button press events with the PC too. This is just a theory, I haven't found anything yet about SimpLink in Google. Can anyone confirm this is possible and tell me how?